# Lebesgue decomposition of increasing function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

Suppose $F$ is right-continuous, and increasing. By lebesgue decomposition,
$F=F_A+F_C+F_J$ where $F_A$ is absolutely continuous, $F_C$ is continuous with $F'_C=0$ a.e., and $F_J$ is pure jump function. Let $\mu=\mu_A+\mu_C+\mu_J$ be the Borel measures associated to each function.

I want to prove that $ \mu_A(E) = \int_E F'(x)dx$ for lebesgue measurable set $E$. However, I am unclear how can I get $\int_E F'(x)dx$. Is $F'= F'_A+F'_C+F'_J$?

Comment: What does $F'$ even mean when $F$ isn't differentiable? It is probably $\mu_A(E) = \int_E F'_A(x)dx$ that is true in this situation.

Comment: This is actually from Stein's Real Analysis, chapter 6 exercise 11. Under appropriate conditions, it says the differentiation of jump function exists ( Theorem 3.14 in the book)

Comment: Oh I see, I'm sorry. Since I'm not sure about that and I don't have the time to look it up, I'll leave this question to someone else. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F'=F_A'+F_C'+F_J'$ a.e. is true and the second and third terms are both $0$ a.e. So $F'=F_A'$ a.e. From this it follows that $\mu_A(E)=\int_E F_A'=\int_A F'$.

Comment: What is $F'$ when $F$ is a ***right continuous*** function?

Comment: Any monotone function is differentiable almost everywhere w.r.t Lebesgue measure. @KurtG.

Comment: Correct. Missed the tiny a.e. in your text. Some like it terse.